# NPM error creating new app on Sails js

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

I have updated nodejs, npm and sails. My current versions are:

```
$ node -v: 5.5.0
$ npm -v: 3.3.12
$ sails -v: 0.11.4
```

This is the log when i'm creating a new app:

```
$ sails new npmtest
Installing dependencies... (this could take a while)
npm WARN deprecated lodash@0.9.2: lodash@<2.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0
npm WARN deprecated grunt-lib-contrib@0.7.1: DEPRECATED. See readme: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-contrib
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<2.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add core-util-is@1.0.2 node_modules/core-util-is
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add minimist@1.1.1 node_modules/geojsonhint/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add isarray@0.0.1 node_modules/isarray
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add JSV@4.0.2 node_modules/JSV
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add underscore@1.6.0 node_modules/nomnom/node_modules/underscore
...
info: Created a new Sails app `npmtest`!
```

Perfect, then `$ cd npmtest` and `$ sails lift`

This is the log:

```
Starting app...

module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'validator'
```

I'm trying to install "validator" manually, but i'm getting:

```
$ npm install validator
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add core-util-is@1.0.2 node_modules/core-util-is
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add minimist@1.1.1 node_modules/geojsonhint/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add isarray@0.0.1 node_modules/isarray
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add JSV@4.0.2 node_modules/JSV
npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running add underscore@1.6.0 node_modules/nomnom/node_modules/underscore
...
npmtest@0.0.0 /Users/Sites/npmtest
└── validator@4.5.1  extraneous
```

But now on sails lift, the reply is the same:

```
Starting app...

module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'validator'
```

What i'm doing wrong? This isn't my first sails app. I have used the new app generator docens of times.

Comment: I'm very interested in your issue here. I make allot of sails apps too, and have been running npm v 0.12.7 which, I believe is ancient, lol. Trying to update to v 5.5.0 I get similar errors on lift. I'm using nvm-win (on my windows instance) to switch back to 0.12.7 and everything runs fine. I can't imagine there is a compatibility issue with 5.5.0. Thoughts?

Comment: hey @edencorbin, check the correct answer. The sails installation was corrupted I think...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your global installation contains packages that are not updated.

Completely removes your SailsJS installation and reinstall again.